# Tab Bar doesn't show up on TabbedPage

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm using Xamarin Forms on Visual Studios 2017. In my PCL, I've created a Tabbed Page and placed children pages inside. However, when I run my code and click on the Tabbed Page, only my first child page (UploadPage) is displayed. I don't see a tab bar at the top or bottom (I'm currently using an Android phone and emulator). Here is the code I have:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xam1;assembly=Xam1"
         x:Class="Xam1.PersonalAccountPage">

<local:UploadPage></local:UploadPage>

<local:MyVideosPage></local:MyVideosPage>

<local:TrainingVideosPage></local:TrainingVideosPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

and the code behind is:

```
public partial class PersonalAccountPage : TabbedPage
```

with the regular constructor.

Is there something I can try to make the TabbedPages work/a reason why they aren't working?

Comment: do you load this page inside navigation page?

Comment: Tested your code with three `ContentPage` as children of `TabbedPage`, works fine.

Comment: Do all your pages have a Title or Icon? Perhaps they're there just not showing anything in their labels.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I tried doing that with this code (in the next comment) but I am only able to see the text from the first page (the Tab bar doesn't show up)

Comment: <TabbedPage.Children>

        <ContentPage Title="Page 1" >
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="TP1"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>

        <ContentPage Title="Page 2" >
            <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="TP2"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage.Content>
        </ContentPage>
 
    </TabbedPage.Children>
  
</TabbedPage>

Comment: @StevenThewissen all of my pages have Titles and I added icons yet they don't show up because there is no tab bar

Comment: @YuriS I navigate from a navigation page to my current page (PersonalAccountPage)

Comment: How does the constructor for your `App.xaml.cs` look? Is this page actually set as the `MainPage` in there?

Comment: Try to remove it from Navigation page (at least for test if that is the problem)

Comment: @YuriS I tried creating a new page but only get a blank white screen (I tried changing the background colors but it didn't affect it) My code is:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xam1;assembly=Xam1"
             x:Class="Xam1.TabTest" Title="TabbedPage" BackgroundColor="Crimson">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="BlueViolet">
            <Label Text="Tab Test Page" FontSize="Large" TextColor="Aqua"></Label>
            <TabbedPage.Children>
                <ContentPage Title="Page 1" Icon="image" >

Comment: <ContentPage.Content>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="TABBED PAGE"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ContentPage.Content>
                </ContentPage>

                <ContentPage Title="Page 2" Icon="image">
                    <ContentPage.Content>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="TABBED PAGE 2"></Label>>

Comment: </StackLayout>
                    </ContentPage.Content>
                </ContentPage>
            </TabbedPage.Children>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</TabbedPage>

Comment: the code behind is: [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
 public partial class TabTest : TabbedPage
 {
  public TabTest ()
  {
   InitializeComponent ();
  }
 }

Comment: @StevenThewissen in my constructor I have  InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new TabTest(); {TabTest is the sample Contentpage I am currently working on}

Comment: Check the rest of your xaml. White page ususally means either crash in page code or bad xaml. Add  complilation attribute above your pages so if you have xaml problems compiler will tell you:     [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class You Page : ContentPage

Answer (score 2):

I have met the same issue.I found it's the style theme problem. Here is how I fixed.
In styles.xml file, I changed to

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>  
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

In Android Manifest.xml, I added

```
    <application android:theme = "@style/MainTheme"/>
```

Comment: In my case it wasn't exactly this - but the clue was in the theme stuff mentioned by Jason. In my case in my MainActivity class I was inheriting from global::Xamarin.forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity - I switched this to FormsAppCompatActivity and my tabs started appearing again. I have also added this as an answer below - rather than leave a potential separate answer as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Place your children page within TabbedPage.Children

```
 <TabbedPage.Children>
   <local:UploadPage></local:UploadPage>
   <local:MyVideosPage></local:MyVideosPage>
 </TabbedPage.Children>
```

OR do it programtically:

```
public MyTabbedPage ()
{           
    InitializeComponent ();            
    Children.Add(new Page1());
    Children.Add(new Page2());             
}
```

Comment: I tried both ways but still do not see the tab bar. I've added the   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xam1;assembly=Xam1" to the <TabbedPage> and given my UploadPage titles. In the code behind, it reads (myClassName) : TabbedPage. Is there anything else I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have not initialized Page's title. 
Do it in constructor like:

```cs
        public MyPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Title = "MyPage";
        }
```

or in XAML. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was similar to the theme stuff mentioned by @jason-ye. In my MainActivity class I was inheriting from global::Xamarin.forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity - I switched this to FormsAppCompatActivity and my tabs started appearing again. I had previously needed to switch the inheritance due to a different build error (red herring.. total waste of time) and ended up with a broken tabbed app ever since.